# Is there a way to make someone unconscious without threat of death?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I keep looking through but not finding anything that talks about knocking someone out, other than like paralysis.

Looking for a way to knock enemies out such that they'll get up after a few hours and be ok.

I could house rule it but I was hoping there was something in RAW for this.

Comment: Is Subdual damage a thing in pathfinder?

Comment: @GMNoob The term *subdual damage* was changed to *nonlethal damage* during the transition between *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* and *3.5*. Some d20 games nonetheless kept the term (e.g. both editions of *Spycraft*).

Answer (score 11):

Most weapons that inflict lethal damage can be used to inflict nonlethal damage if the wielder takes a -4 penalty to his attack roll beforehand. Learn more about inflicting nonlethal damage with weapons here: [Nonlethal Damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Nonlethal-Damage).

To explain further, when a creature takes nonlethal damage

> Do not deduct the nonlethal damage number from [its] current hit points. [This] is not "real" damage. Instead, when... nonlethal damage equals... current hit points, [the creature is] staggered (see below), and when it exceeds current hit points, [it falls] unconscious.

Also...

> If a creature's nonlethal damage is equal to his total maximum hit points (not his current hit points), all further nonlethal damage is treated as lethal damage.

So a dude has to *really* be beating on the fool to kill him with nonlethal damage. For example, a creature with a maximum of 10 hp who takes 11 points of nonlethal damage takes 1 point of lethal damage and is unconscious. Then the dude would have to continue beating the unconscious foe for 9 *more* points of damage *plus* the unconscious creature's Constitution score to kill him.

Unless the dude's whipping out his Monster Shark Turbo Strike or whatever and using it for enough nonlethal damage to *both* A) equal the foe's maximum hp *and* B) equal the foe's remaining actual hp *plus* the foe's Constitution score, the foe should be fine in a few hours.

> You heal nonlethal damage at the rate of 1 hit point per hour per character level. When a spell or ability cures hit point damage, it also removes an equal amount of nonlethal damage.

---

Aside from that, there are **weapons** which specifically deal nonlethal damage by default, the list includes the [sap](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/sap), [whip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/whip), [bolas](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/bolas) and others. With these, you take a -4 penalty while attempting to inflict lethal damage.

Finally, a character can improve her ability to inflict nonlethal damage using the following **feats**:

1. [Bludgeoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/bludgeoner-combat) - no -4 penalty when using lethal bludgeoning weapons for nonlethal attacks.
2. [Stage Combatant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stage-combatant-combat) - no -4 penalty when using (any) lethal weapon in which you have Weapon Focus. Despite the theatrical name, this is also useful for Paladins and any "merciful" PC with a signature weapon.
3. [Merciful Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/merciful-spell-metamagic) - a *metamegic* feat which allows a caster to cast a lethal spell as nonlethal (has no level increase).
4. [Betraying Blow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/betraying-blow-combat) - use *Bluff* for extra nonlethal damage while fighting 1 on 1.
5. [Sap Adept](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/sap-adept-combat) & [Sap Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/sap-master-combat) - allow a Rogue to deal a lot of nonlethal damage using sap and sneak-attacks.
6. [Pinning Knockout](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pinning-knockout-combat) - allows a Monk to inflict a lot of nonlethal damage while grappling.
7. [Knockout Artist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/knockout-artist) - extra nonlethal damage when combining sneak-attack and unarmed strike (useful for Rogue/Monk, Ninja and some other exotic combinations).
8. [Merciful Bane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/merciful-bane) - allows Inquisitors (and others with *Bane* class feature) to switch their weapon to nonlethal damage while under the effect of *Bane* (no -4 on attacks, *Bane* extra damage becomes nonlethal too).

Comment: Yes, but if you knock someone out with non-lethal damage, they begin to take lethal damage don't they?  So they need to be stabilized which was something I was trying to avoid.

Comment: No, that's the point of nonlethal damage. Once they drop below 0, they are just _unconscious_ not _dying/dead_.

Comment: OH! I see, I was understanding that non-lethal damage also turns into lethal damage once they take their max HP in non-lethal.  So in your example, I was thinking that once the creature took 11 points of non-lethal damage he now had -1 HP and would need to stabilize but really he is just unconscious and with a current 9 HP is that right?

Comment: @Nerevar Yes, in the example the creature with 10 hp maximum who suffers 11 points of nonlethal damage suffers only 1 hp of lethal damage and falls unconscious. No further damage is sustained unless, after all this, the unconscious creature is *again* whacked by the club-wielding dude ("Gotta make sure he stays unconscious. He might be faking"). Be sure to warn such club-happy PCs that the media is always scrying.

Comment: @HeyICanChan - great answer, I think it can be improved by mentioning nonlethal weapons (and perhaps some of the relevant feats, spells and poisons to knockout someone). Care to elaborate (or may I edit and add that?)

Comment: @G0BLiN You are welcome to edit that in. Expect me to edit it again when you're done, though. ;-)

Comment: @HeyICanChan - done, hope you approve (obviously feel free to add, edit or discard anything - that's your answer after all). Relevant spells and poisons can still be added, I don't have the time to dedicate to it right now...

Answer (score 0):

This works if 3.5 materials are accepted in the game, not sure about PF-only:

While subdual damage is a good way to go, sometimes you have to do things like that quick - like, in a round, or so. In those cases, you could use some of the non-lethal (and thus, acceptable for evil adventurers as much, as for the allies of the good cosmic forces) poisons to achieve this:

> **Sleep-Smoke** (DC 15 Unconscious/Unconscious 1d3 mins) (Waterdeep, City of Splendors 152)
>
> **Drow Poison** (Injury DC 13, Unconsciousness/Unconsciousness)(DMG)
>
> **Oil of Taggit** (0/Unconsciousness, ingested)(DMG)
>
> **Sssartisss** (Paralysis 2d6 mins/Unconscious)(Serpent Kingdoms)
>
> **Lizardfolk Sleep Poison** (Contact, Unconsciousness 1d3 rounds/Unconsciousness 1d3 hours)(Serpent Kingdoms)
>
> **Wild Dwarf Knockout Poison** (Slows for 5 rounds, then unconsciousness) (PGtF)
>
> **Homonculus venom** (Sleep)
>
> **Pseudodragon venom** (Sleep)

For more ingormation, read the [Arsenic & Old Lace: The Poison Handbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=4854.0), the part about poisons for good-aligned adventurers and crowd control gives you the full list of others non-lifethreatening poison effects (and the rest of the handbook will explain how to use them more efficiently)